# What is more convenient? To book a roundtrip ticket with E-dreams or two separate tickets?

Tags: tickets

What is more convenient, to book a roundtrip ticket with E-dreams or single tickets in their own respective airline websites?
For example, if there's a roundtrip flight with Lufthansa and AirFrance, would it be convenient to book the whole ticket with E-dreams or to book the one way flight and the return separately? Would I avoid to pay commission with the latter?

Comment: A return flight is typically cheaper than booking separately. Have you compared the cost?

Comment: The online reviews of eDreams are overwhelmingly negative, so there’s that.

Answer (score 8):

> What is more convenient?

**It's far more convenient and safer to book with the airlines.**

Almost all airlines allow you to book and manage flights on directly on their website. Regardless of what happens it's very clear that the only two parties involved are you and the airline. You will get MUCH better customer service this way, should you need it (Seat reservations, special meals, covid questions, changes, etc.)

Source: https://www.edreams.net/images/shared/pdf/US/flight_conditions.pdf

E-Dream is a broker that buys tickets on your behalf, which creates a complicated double contract. From their terms and condition:

> You will enter into two agreements: (a) one agreement directly with the Travel Supplier(s) relating to the supply of the ordered travel service and (b) one agreement with eDreams relating to the supply of a mediation service.

If you need any services, the airline will not talk to you since you booked through a third party and e-dreams will not talk to you either because their terms & condition states it's not their problem. Let's look at a cancellation and changes

> The chance to cancel or change a travel product or service purchased through this Platform, as well as the way to do so, will depend on the terms and conditions of your Travel Supplier(s), which are usually according to the kind of fare chosen (i.e. low cost fares do not usually allow changes or cancellations). eDreams can assist You to find out whether Your fare allows changes or cancellation and, if you wish, eDreams can also manage your request with your Travel Supplier(s), by charging a service fee of FIFTY EUROS (50€) per person and route cancelled and/or changed.

Translation: it's not our problem. If you give us 50 Euros we'll try but there is absolutely no guarantee something will come of it.

So you are stuck in customer service limbo which is very risky especially given the travel unpredictability of the pandemic.

The **ONLY** reason to book through a 3rd party website is a massive price difference that warrants the additional risk and hassle.

Two one-way tickets are no problem at all. If there is no price difference, I actually prefer two one-ways over a round-trip since it's easier to manage and you have more options if plans change.

Comment: I agree in general but there is one advantage of a roundtrip ticket (booked with the airline) over two one-ways which is that if the airline cancels the outbound segment and you decide not to travel you can generally get a refund on the whole ticket. If you have two one ways then the fact that the airline cancelled the outbound would not be justification to get a refund on the return.

Comment: @ajd On the other hand, on a roundtrip booked with the airline, if you miss your first flight, they will often also cancel the return fight. So whether one is better than the other may depend on a lot on each specific situation

Comment: United once forced my to pay $250 penalty for NOT taking a leg that I had already fully paid for by threating to cancel the last (transatlantic) leg. Lesson learned: don't entangle legs more than you have to